# sklearn weighted Elastic Nets

Tags: statistics, scikit-learn, linear-regression

When I use the `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` module, I found it support the `sample_weight` variable in the `fit` method. I was wondering why other linear_model (e.g., `ElasticNet`, `LASSO`, `RidgeRegression`, etc) does not currently support that (as I don't find this option in their `fit` method).

I check the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L487) of `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` and found they use the `_rescale_data` method following the [following logic](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/352), where basically multiply the sqrt of the weight diagonal metric to both `X` and `y`. I am wondering if I can manually use this `_rescale_data` trick in other regularized function, for example:

```
EN = ElasticNet()
X, y = _rescale_data(X, y, sample_weight)
EN.fit(X, y)
```

Of course I can do that, but will this make theoretical soundness?